# Can you manipulate a database file with javascript?

Tags: javascript, sql

Is it possible to load a .db file from local machine with javascript to perform CRUD operations on it with sql? I would also like to export the edited file on to the local machine.

I know javascript has indexedDB is it possible to load that from and into a file?

Answer (score 0):

There are node modules for many common types of databases. [Here are some modules for IndexedDB specifically](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=indexeddb). You will likely want to use a server framework like Express, Koa, or Hapi, in addition to the database driver.

Comment: the issue is I dont want to use a server. If I could use my web app on a file that would be perfect.

Comment: Ah, then yes, but I'm not sure if it's possible to work with as a DB file. Everything stored in indexeddb should be serializable so it can be saved out as JSON and re-imported from JSON. There are some details on that in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17783719/import-and-export-indexeddb-data.